# Why we send id instead of whole object in workers?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

In Ruby practice is to send id instead of object in workers. Isn't that kind of CPU consuming process because we have to retrieve Object again from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several reasons:

1. Saves space on the queue, also transfer time (app => queue, queue => workers).
2. Often it is easier to fetch fresh object from the database (as opposed to retrieving cached copy from the queue)
3. Argument to `Resque.enqueue` must be JSON-serializable. Complex objects not always can be serialized.

Comment: JSON-encodable is the big one.  Definitely better to avoid using a stale object with asynchronous stuff like this though.  Might testing the job classes *considerably* easier too.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it the reasons are pretty obvious:

- your object may change between the time te action is queued and handled and in general you don't want an outdated object.
- an id a a lot lighter to transport than a whole object which you will need to serialize it in json/yaml or anything else.
- if you need the associations the problem just got even worse :)

But in the end it depends on your application, if you only need some informations you can just send them to your worker directly without even using the full model.